# Upload files to SharePoint through Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, upload, office365api

I am trying to upload files to SharePoint through Python.
I have tried the following:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

def get_sharepoint_context_using_user():
sharepoint_url = 'https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/Afolder/'

user_credentials = UserCredential("login", "password")

ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url).with_credentials(user_credentials)

return ctx



def upload_to_sharepoint(file_name: str):
sp_relative_url='https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/Afolder/some%20thing/Forms/AllItems.aspx'

ctx = get_sharepoint_context_using_user()
ctx = get_sharepoint_context_using_user()
target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(sp_relative_url)


with open(file_name, 'rb') as content_file:
    file_content = content_file.read()
    target_folder.upload_file(file_name, file_content).execute_query()
```

After I try to call the function of uploading

```
upload_to_sharepoint(os.path.join(path_from, file_word))
```

I got the following mistake:

```
ValueError: Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf
```

Perhaps, you know what might be the reason of it. I tried different variations, but it did not work.
The tricky part is that I was granted an access not to the whole folder, I mean https://companyname.sharepoint.com, but to the part of it beginning from https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/Afolder.
Could it be the reason of this problem? If yes, is there any opportunity to upload to folders through Python, when there is such a limited access.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that this error is more of a problem with the authentication credentials when the authentication token cannot be retrieved from the specified URL. So in general terms, not only that the folder does not have the authorization.

Comment: I used credentials (login and password) that I usually use at work. However, when I manually go to that folder I do not need to put any credentials there, the program automatically permit me to see uploaded data there.